# Effect after hover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, hover

I'm doing [this](https://codepen.io/stefalber/pen/qVgEYd) on codepen for freecodecamp challenger and I want to see my button's animation after hover effect. Does anyone know the solution for this?  Maybe I did something wrong in the code. Here my code for the button `#random`.
I did the `reverse` animation and then I put it in `#random` but it doesn't work.

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}
.message{
  margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
  padding:20px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top:70px;
}
h2{
  margin:auto;
  width:90%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color:white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#random{
  background:black;
  border:1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -20px -50px; 
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:10%;
  color:#595959;
  animation: reverse 0.6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#random:hover{
  background:black;
  border:1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -20px -50px; 
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:10%;
  animation: clickmes 0.6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes clickmes {
    0% {
        color: #595959;
    }
    25% {
        color: #707070;
    }
    50% {
        color: #a3a3a3;
    }
    100% {
        color: white;
    }
}
 @keyframes reverse {
    0% {
        color: white;
    }
    25% {
        color: #a3a3a3;
    }
    50% {
        color: #707070;
    }
    100% {
        color: #595959;
    }
 }
```

```html
  <div id="social"><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world"
  data-size="large" id= "tweet" class="fa fa-twitter" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
  <div id="where1" class="message"><h2>I need random quotes from Api here.</h2>
    <h4></h4>
</div>

<button id="random">I'm a button</button>
```

Comment: Please clarify, what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe with new changes it's clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if a css animation is required for this, but if not I would use a transition instead. Transitions are much easier to control for things that aren't too complicated. Please see my snippet below.

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
}
#random {
  background:black;
  border:1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: -20px -50px; 
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  right:10%;
  color:#595959;
  transition: color .5s ease;
 }
 
 #random:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
 }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="random">Button Text</button>
```

You can also read more about how transitions work [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: Tank you for this answer. This works fine for this particular case, but i'm looking for general solution.

Comment: Your welcome. I am not 100% sure you can achieve this using purely CSS. You may need to use JavaScript/jQuery to add/remove a class from the button in order for this to work. Please someone correct me if I am wrong.